# How do I exclude rows with a null value in the derived column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a query where I am calculating the next value using the LEAD function. The problem is that I need to remove the rows that contain a NULL in this "next value" column. I can't do a `WHERE NextProductID IS NULL` because the column is calculated with the LEAD funciton.

Example code:

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, ProductID, LEAD(ProductID) OVER(PARTITION BY BusinessEntityID ORDER BY BusinessEntityID) AS NextProductID
FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor
ORDER BY BusinessEntityID, ProductID
```

I'm using AdventureWorks2014. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap your query in another select and perform filtering there:

```
SELECT data.BusinessEntityID, data.ProductID, data.NextProductID
FROM (
    -- Your original SELECT becomes the "table"
    SELECT BusinessEntityID, ProductID, 
        LEAD(ProductID) OVER(PARTITION BY BusinessEntityID ORDER BY BusinessEntityID) AS NextProductID
    FROM Purchasing.ProductVendor
    ORDER BY BusinessEntityID, ProductID
) data
WHERE data.NextProductID IS NOT NULL   -- perform the filtering you need
```